# Add image programmatically

Tags: android

I have several images in my mipmap folder and I want to add them to the screen at a specific location and then move them.  Here is the code I thought should work:

```
ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
item.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ball);
```

Where ball is a valid png file.  Why doesn't this code show the image?

Comment: Because you don't tell the UI where to put the ImageView

Comment: is there any error in stack trace?

Comment: and that too! you are not telling where to put your image.  This is created programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assumed that your xml is look like this.
Xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/layout">

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And try this one in your class file(i.e in activity)

```
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.add_symbol);
//which adds the imageview to your layout
layout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: This worked!  The thing I was missing was this:

android:id="@+id/layout"

I couldn't reference the parent layout to add the image.  Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you are creating an image view unattached to any view. The instance is there, but it doesn't know where to render.

If you know where you want to insert it, lets say, some LinearLayout with id image_container, you could do something like (and I'm being very simplistic about it!):

```
  ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
  item.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ball);

  LinearLayout layout = activity.findById(R.id.image_container);
  layout.addView(item)
```

You might also want to use `item.setScaleType( ... )` in order to get the desired scaling.

That being said, please keep in mind that the proper way of adding several items programatically would be using something like a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Also, in order to get a nice performance for you images loading and rendering, something like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) would be very useful.